# Let $f(x)=\int_1^\infty \frac{\cos t}{x^2+t^2}dt$. Then which of the following are correct?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

Let $f(x)=\int_1^\infty \frac{\cos t}{x^2+t^2}dt$. Then which of the following are correct?

1. $f$ is bounded on $\mathbb R$
2. $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$
3. $f$ is not defined everywhere on $\mathbb R$
4. $f$ is not continuous on $\mathbb R$

My try:

$|f(x)|=|\int_1^\infty \frac{\cos t}{x^2+t^2}dt|\leq \int_1^\infty |\frac{\cos t}{x^2+t^2}|dt\leq \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2+t^2}dt=\frac{1}{x}\tan^{-1}(\frac{t}{x})|_1^\infty $. Let $g(x)= \frac{1}{x}\tan^{-1}(\frac{t}{x})|_1^\infty$ is not continuous at $0$. That doesn't mean that $f$ is not bounded.

For continuity,
$|f(x)-f(y)|=|\int_1^\infty \frac{\cos t}{x^2+t^2}dt-\int_1^\infty \frac{\cos t}{y^2+t^2}dt|\leq \int_1^\infty |\frac{1}{x^2+t^2}-\frac{1}{y^2+t^2}|dt=\int_1^\infty |\frac{y^2-x^2}{(x^2+t^2)(y^2+t^2)}|dt $. I am not conclude from here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For all $c > 1$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$,

$$\left|\int_1^c \frac{\cos t}{x^2 + t^2} \, dt \right| \leqslant \int_1^c \frac{|\cos t|}{x^2 + t^2} \, dt \leqslant\int_1^c \frac{dt}{t^2} \leqslant1 - \frac{1}{c} < 1$$

This implies both that $f$ is bounded and the improper integral converges **uniformly** by the Weierstrass M-test.

With uniform convergence it is straightforward to prove continuity, since

$$|f(x) - f(y)| \leqslant \left|\int_c^\infty\frac{\cos t}{x^2 + t^2} \, dt \right|+  \left|\int_c^\infty\frac{\cos t}{y^2 + t^2} \, dt \right|\\+  \int_1^c\left|\frac{\cos t}{x^2 + t^2}- \frac{\cos t}{y^2 + t^2}\right| \, dt $$

For any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $c$ such that the first two terms on the RHS are less than $\epsilon/3$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.  You should be able to handle the third term.

Comment: So, (A) and (B) are the correct options.right?

Comment: @Mathgeek: Yes and there is a general theorem that for a uniformly convergent improper integral of the form $F(x) = \int_a^\infty f(x,t) \, dt$ where the integrand is continuous, $F$ is continuous.

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Mathgeek: You're welcome. and you came close but stopped with the bound $1/(x^2+t^2)$ when you could have gone further.

Comment: I integrated right there. But I got an unbounded bound. So, I thought that I losed there.

Comment: how are you using Weierstrass M test here? @RRL

Comment: @ymir:  With $t \geqslant 1$ we have  $\left|  \frac{\cos t}{x^2 + t^2}\right|  =  \frac{|\cos t|}{x^2 + t^2} \leqslant \frac{1}{x^2 + t^2} \leqslant \frac{1}{t^2}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.  Since $t \mapsto 1/t^2$ is integrable on $[1,\infty)$, the improper integral is uniformly convergent  by the Weierstrass test.  See Theorem 6 [here](https://fac.ksu.edu.sa/sites/default/files/trench_improper_functions.pdf).